# Are there multiple ways to calculate the non-centrality parameter (t-distribution)?

Tags: statistical-power, non-centrality-parameter

I have a repeated measure design and I want to calculate the power to detect a future hypothetical % decline in a mean, but found multiple versions of this calculation - each involve something called an non-centrality parameter (ncp). The 3 equations I found yield different results for this parameter and I'm not sure which one is correct for my data. The power from equation ncp_3 matches the `stats` package calculation, but the assumption for a correlation between repeated measures = 0.5 1. seems very strong and 2. the other equations for ncp don't require it, so is this assumption necessary? Which version of ncp is the correct one? I prefer the `pwrss` package because taking into account the correlation between repeated measures seems like an important step, but I'm not sure how to estimate it.

```
n = 47         # Sample size per group
d = -0.114     # Difference in means
sd = 0.4352    # Sample standard dev.
var = sd^2     # Sample variance
cor = 0.5      # Assumed correlation between repeated measures (R assumes this)
mu_0 = 0.3799  # Starting mean
mu = 0.2659    # 30% hypothetical future decline in mean

ncp_1 = (mu - mu_0) * sqrt(n)/var # Reference 1.

ncp_2 = d / (sd / sqrt(n - 1)) # Reference 2.

ncp_3 = d * sqrt(n) / sqrt(2*sd^2 * (1 - cor)) # Reference 3.

pwrss::power.t.test(ncp = c(ncp_1, ncp_2, ncp_3), 
                    df = n-1,
                    alpha = 0.05,
                    alternative = "less",
                    plot = FALSE)

     power ncp.alt ncp.null alpha df  t.crit
 0.9922368  -4.126        0  0.05 46 1.67866
 0.5420315  -1.777        0  0.05 46 1.67866
 0.5495299  -1.796        0  0.05 46 1.67866
```

The power calculated from the `stats` package matches ncp_3, so is that the correct one?

```
stats::power.t.test(n = 47, 
                    sd = 0.4352, 
                    delta = 0.114, 
                    alternative = "one.sided", 
                    type = "paired")

     Paired t test power calculation 

              n = 47
          delta = 0.114
             sd = 0.4352
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.5495299
    alternative = one.sided

NOTE: n is number of *pairs*, sd is std.dev. of *differences* within pairs
```

1. [Ref 1.][1]
2. [Ref 2.][2]
3. [Ref 3.][3]

[1]: https://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/stats/html/TDist.html#:~:text=Let%20T%3D%20(mX%20%2D%20m0,*%20sqrt(n)%2Fsigma.
[2]: [What's wrong with this approach to computing power?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/326940/whats-wrong-with-this-approach-to-computing-power)
[3]: https://community.rstudio.com/t/which-power-test-should-i-use/176807/2

Comment: Your code adaptation of the first reference is incorrect. The reference doesn't say you should divide by `var` in the ncp formula (ncp_1), but by `sd` (sigma). I don't have the time right now to check the rest of your code, but maybe you should re-read the other references to check if another similar mistake occurred in your code for the other formulas.

Comment: (By the way, you should also edit your question, something weird happened to the links!)

Comment: @J-J-J Aha, thank you! I'll try and fix the links, but your sharp eye fixed the code and now both equations 1 and 3 produce the same power calculation. Additionally, equation 2 is actually supposed to be sqrt(n), not the sqrt of df (n-1). Cheers!

Comment: Glad to help! In case you're interested, Daniël Lakens has a useful discussion of various "versions" of Cohen's d, it's available to read for free here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3840331/